# How can I solve this problem 'No duplicate props allowed react/jsx-no-duplicate-props'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am referring this post [this post](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/material-ui-dialog-customization-f69548e5c059) for finishing up a custom dialog.
But I keep getting warning **No duplicate props allowed  react/jsx-no-duplicate-props**

And the following code is the place holds props.
How can I solve this problem ?

```
const DialogTitle = withStyles(styles)((props) => {
    const { children, classes, onClose, ...other } = props;
    return (
        <MuiDialogTitle disableTypography className={classes.root} {...other}>
            <Typography variant="h6">{children}</Typography>
            {onClose ? (
                <IconButton aria-label="close" className={classes.closeButton} onClick={onClose}>
                    <CloseIcon />
                </IconButton>
            ) : null}
        </MuiDialogTitle>
    );
});
```

Comment: At which code line do you get this warning? Maybe {...other} prop has the `disableTypography`

Comment: @chelsey lee, May I know the value stored in the other varibale??

Comment: I agree with @PathumKalhan, I guess there is `disableTypography` or `className` in the `other` object, could you please add `console.log(other)` in the 3rd line so we could figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `other` contains either `className` or `disableTypography` in it. Most probably it's `className`. So you should extract it and do something about it (let's say combine it with `classes.root`):

```
const { children, classes, onClose, className ...other } = props;
return (
    <MuiDialogTitle disableTypography className={`${classes.root} ${className}`} {...other}>
```